# Switching from Subversion to PVCS Serena

Tags: svn, pvcs, serena

My company has been using Subversion for a very long time and now I have been told that we will be switching to PVCS and am in charge of the migration. I can't find much information where people are switching from Subversion to PVCS, it's mostly the other way around. Anyone every switched from Subversion to PVCS?

Thanks!

Comment: and Why is your company moving the other way around?

Comment: From what I have been told, one project that my department will be taking over was started in PVCS and since it's a bigger project, they don't want to switch it to subversion and instead are trying to move all other projects to PVCS in order to have only one version control system. I tried convincing them but they have already made their decision.

Comment: Too bad for you... you will find all sorts of documentation to upgrade... but downgrade; I suspect you might get something!!! All the best!

Comment: Yep, haven't found anything yet! Thanks

Comment: I would say find something on Serena -> SVN and see what are the steps... and then you have to reverse them. This seems to be the best bet!!!

Comment: @user1596039 your best option would be to quit and get another job. I tried PVCS and trust me... never again !!

Answer (score 2):

For commercial VCSes, it's the vendor's duty to support migration if they want others to use their product. Your best bet is to [ask them](http://www.serena.com/index.php/en/products/other-products/pvcs-vm/). (Maybe when your superiours see their service bills, they'll have a second thought...)

On the other hand, [their Issue & Defect Management solution has an SVN connector](http://www.serena.com/index.php/en/solutions/app-dev-delivery/issue-defect-management/scm-connectors/). Maybe that can be a alternative deal.